# How to make D3.js path generator append two points?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path

Using D3.js I would like to create a graph that has horizontal lines, which are connected by a line. See this example: http://s15.postimg.org/7ffms1f7f/tmp.png

With the help of some tutorials I managed to display the horizontal bars using *line*. jsfiddle.net /m2p1xky9/4/

For displaying connected bars it made sense to me to use *path*. https://jsfiddle.net/jaa07n6m/2/

```
// Append Path:
   var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .interpolate("linear")

   var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
          .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
          .attr("stroke", "blue")
          .attr("stroke-width", 2)
          .attr("fill", "none");
```

But I am failing to implement it the right way.

I guess I would need to make the *lineFunction* append two points. My approach doesn't work:

```
   var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .interpolate("linear")
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter)+x.rangeBand(); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .interpolate("linear");
```

What would be the right way to implement it?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @cool-blue You did. Actually my question was how to draw one continuous line. But your solution is even better, giving me the ability to use different thickness for the horizontal segments. Guess my question was not explicit enough. However, I hoped there is a more elegant solution than accessing the data array directly. Something like the data()-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Strategy

The line function doesn't care how many point there are, it expects an array of points and it just joins them all.  The accessor functions are applied to *every* point you feed it.
You need a collection of lines having one less member than the data so you need to bind some dummy data, then you need to construct members with two points and feed them to the line function.

### Code

```js
 data = [

   {
   letter: "A",
   frequency: .08167
   }, {
   letter: "B",
   frequency: .01492
   }, {
   letter: "C",
   frequency: .02782
   }, {
   letter: "D",
   frequency: .04253
   }, {
   letter: "E",
   frequency: .12702
   }
 ];

 var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

 //Define X axis:
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

 //Define y axis:
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "%");

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


 x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.letter; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.frequency; })]);


 // Append X-Axis:
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


 // Append Y-Axis:
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)

 // Append Lines:
 svg.selectAll(".line")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("x1", function (d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("y1", function (d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("x2", function (d) { return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand(); })
  .attr("y2", function (d) { return y(d.frequency); })

 var lineFunction2 = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function (d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate("linear")

 var lineGraph = svg.selectAll(".connect")
  .data(d3.range(data.length-1))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "connect")
  .attr("d", function(d, i) {
   var p1 = data[i], p2 = data[i+1];
   return lineFunction2([
   {x: x(p1.letter) + x.rangeBand(), y:y(p1.frequency)}, 
   {x: x(p2.letter), y:y(p2.frequency)}
   ])
  })
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```css
.line {
  
  stroke: gray;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.axis {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .x.axis path {
   display: none;
  }  </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```